# unable to execute codeigniter query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i am trying to execute query like: `select*from bookdetails where quantity>0 ORDER BY created_date DESC`

but i am getting error  like `Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in...`
Please help me to solve this issue.

```
public function get_all_book_list_ByCreatedDateDSC($limit, $start,$sortsesval)
{
    $this->load->database();  
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);  

     $query=$this->db->join('coverdetails', 'coverdetails.cover_id = bookdetails.cover_id')->order_by('created_date', 'DESC')->get_where('bookdetails',array('quantity >', '0')); 

  if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
return false;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->where('quantity >', $id); 
$this->db->join('coverdetails', 'coverdetails.cover_id = bookdetails.cover_id');
$this->db->order_by('bookdetails.created_date', 'desc');
$this->db->limit($limit, $start);
$query = $this->db->get('bookdetails');
        if($query -> num_rows() == 1)
                    return $query->result_array();
       else
         return false;
```

Comment: i tried your code. But still the same error. if i change `created_date` to `book_title` them i am getting the output. In my table `created_date` is of datetime . And in all rows i have inserted value `2013-03-02 02:12:36` for `created_date`  . Is that error because of created_date? please explain

Comment: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htd

Comment: I think both table have same field name created_date so instead of this : $this->db->order_by('created_date', 'desc'); use this:
$this->db->order_by('bookdetails.created_date', 'desc');

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is telling you that $query is not an object. You cant call a member function on a non-object!

Your "join" method is not returning an object.

Try putting `print_r($query)` or `var_dump($query)` after you set $query, to find out exactly WHAT it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try your function like this

```
public function get_all_book_list_ByCreatedDateDSC($limit, $start,$sortsesval)
{
    $this->load->database();  
    return  $this->db
                        ->join('coverdetails', 'coverdetails.cover_id = bookdetails.cover_id')
                        ->order_by('created_date', 'DESC')
                        ->limit($limit, $start)
                        ->get_where('bookdetails',array('quantity >', '0'))
                        ->result_array();
}
```

When your query returns null(found no record) you wont be able to access the object because in $query it is null. You need to return the data in array format so use result_array. For detail see [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html); Using this you dont need to loop through object. It will give you ready-made array.

In the controller you can check if the result is null or array.

Comment: i tried your code. But still the same error. if i change `created_date` to `book_title` them i am getting the output. In my table `created_date` is of datetime . And in all rows i have inserted value `2013-03-02 02:12:36` for `created_date`  . Is that error because of created_date? please explain

Comment: same error as i specified in my question `Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in.`

Comment: but i dont have num_rows() in my answer. How come this error comes?

Comment: Sorry Error: `Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object in `

Comment: Show your full code. Are you sure you are writing code in model?

Comment: and are you calling constructor in model

Comment: in my model its `function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }`